# Operatorial matrix

Tags: matrix

Suppose I have a matrix M=$\begin{pmatrix} A(p) & B(p) \\ C(p) & D(p)\end{pmatrix}$.

I want to apply some operatorial matrix E such that

EM=$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \partial_p & \\ \partial_p & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A(p) & B(p) \\ C(p) & D(p)\end{pmatrix}$.

How can I create such an operatorial matrix ? I cannot do this explicitly because M is a product of complicated matrices, and I have to apply E several times.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Perhaps you could carry out the product normally like a matrix product then replace the `Times`'s at the right levelspec with the action of the operator or with an `Apply`. I'm not qualified to give an answer on pattern matching though...

Comment: `Inner[Operate, {{(0 &) &, Derivative[1]}, {Derivative[1], (0 &) &}}, M, Plus]`. Use `Nest[]` as needed.